# Scroll div on Mouseover with Angular 4/6 Animation

Tags: angular

Looking for Angular animation to scroll div top and bottom on mouse over, on mouseout we should clear the scrolling.

Exactly similar kind of animation.

http://www.solucior.com/13-Scroll_div_with_javascript.html

```
function scrollDiv(divId, depl) {
   var scroll_container = document.getElementById(divId);
   scroll_container.scrollTop -= depl;
   timer1 = setTimeout('scrollDiv("'+divId+'", '+depl+')', 30);
}
```

This is Java script code. But i am looking for Angular Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the steps are pretty basic Angular. I'm sure the community would appreciate it if you showed that you put some effort into finding the solution yourself. specifically, parts 1 and 3 are pretty basic. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that you gave it an effort and are still stumped :-)

1. instead of `onmouseover=` and `onmouseout=`, you will use `(mouseover)=` and `(mouseout)=`, putting a function from the component's class after the `=`. Learn more about [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding---event-)
2. instead of passing an ID, in Angular you can use a template reference variable. In the element tag that you want a reference to, add `#someElementName`, and then when you call the function on a mouse event, pass `someElementName`. Learn more about [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)
3. `timer1` will become a class member of the component (`this.timer1 = setTimout...`). Learn more about [component basics](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#introduction-to-components)

[a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mouseover-animate?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with the result